# Is Jersey1.8 still got support from community?

Tags: java, jersey-1.0

I need to know whether Jersey 1.8 still get support from community or not

Answer (score 0):

Yes jersey 1.8 still has support from community...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What kind of support does the community is providing .ex : bug fixing, etc. ?? How long are they going to provide the support ? where can I check these kind of information ?

Comment: Just google it and follow numerous links... Then only you can know... I just know that yes they provide support...